# Chrome Extension Not Enabling

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was making adjustments to the manifest file and there was an error, I then deleted the lines and as you can see the manifest no longer has errors but the extension wont enable...  I've had to reinstall the package before but I lost all of my indexedDB data so hoping someone can help prevent that again...  On Chrome OS, here's a video of what's going on:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA2KVlVFTQtQ0ZRXzFwSm03enM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Reloading does NOT delete the data. Reinstalling does. When manifest.json is modified reloading is required.

Comment: you're right, I had to reinstall, not reload

Comment: when the manifest has an error, the extension shows up with a screen looking like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA2KVlVFTQtY01kVTR1RE0tRE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: just had to restart the machine apparently